# Pass variables into drawRect in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, drawrect

I want to pass array of colors into drawRect in swift, how can I do that? (I'm getting alot of errors..)

```
class GradientColorView : UIView {

    static let colors : NSArray = NSArray()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    class func initWithColors(colors :NSArray) {

    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        println(self.colors)
        println("drawRect has updated the view")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class has color as static variable which is just like a class variable and it is let which means that is is immutable constant. You would need to change that let to var if you want it to be modifiable. So, you cannot access that from instance. I would propose you to change that to instance variable which makes it easy to do drawing call when colors changes.

You could do something like this,

```
class GradientColorView : UIView {

    var colors : NSArray = NSArray() {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    class func initWithColors(colors :NSArray) {

    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        println(self.colors)
        println("drawRect has updated the view")
    }
}
```

Then you can update the colors from the instance of gradientView which will redraw it again,

```
let gradientView = GradientColorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
gradientView.colors = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.orangeColor(), UIColor.purpleColor()]
```

Comment: Thank you very much man, you solved me the problem and also I've learned something new!